# Can I get a "base URL" in WordPress within a template file?

Tags: php, wordpress, base-url

Usually in my PHP apps I have a *base URL* setup so I can do things like this

```
<a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>tom/jones">Tom</a>
```

Then I can move my site from development to production and swap it easily and have the change go site wide (and it seems more reliable than `<base href="" />`.

I'm doing up a WordPress theme, and I am wondering, does WordPress have anything like this built in, or do I need to redefine my own?

I can see `ABSPATH`, but that is the absolute file path in the file system, not something from the document root.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`get_bloginfo('wpurl');` would be the preferred method of getting the base url of your WordPress installation. This always returns the absolute base url for the install where as `get_bloginfo('url');` is for the actual blog address of your WordPress install.

Comment: In wordpress 3.5.1 I had to put bloginfo('url'); - without "get_"

Comment: get_bloginfo() returns the url whereas bloginfo() will output the url. So <? echo get_bloginfo('url') ?> is the same as <? bloginfo('url') ?>

Comment: @Sy Holloway I find that I get different outputs for those, actually. bloginfo() seems to output an actual base, in my case "http://localhost", whereas get_bloginfo outputs the site base, "http://localhost/directory".

Answer (score 21):

Yes, you can use `get_bloginfo('url')` just like that or define a constant...

```
define('BASE_URL', get_bloginfo('url'));
```

If you are working on a template and want the URL fragment to that theme folder, use...

```
bloginfo('template_directory');
```

Answer (score 10):

You can try using

```
<?php echo home_url(); ?>
```

By using this can get site url like  www.xyz.com

```
<?php echo home_url('/contact'); ?>
```

By using this syntax you will get url like  www.xyz.com/contact

Comment: Documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/home_url/

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can get "base URL" with a simple function.

```
<?php echo get_bloginfo('url') ?>
```

after that with `/` you can reach to any page just type the page name.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the built in wordpress function `site_url()` which retrieves the URL for the current site.

Take a look at [site_url](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/site_url/) for more details.

**EX:**

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('tom/jones'); ?>">Tom</a>
```